# Powershell Loop Through File

Tags: powershell

I use the following piece of Powershell code to loop through all subfolders in a given directory and grab the file name, last write time and row count of all the csv files and store them in a Sql Server table.  This all works fine.  I now need to change the script so that instead of pointing it at a directory and it loops through gathering the information on every csv file, I need it to simply look at the contents of a text file which will have the full paths of the files to gather information on.  Here is an example of the file layout:

D:\Temp\AllTheFolders\SubFolder1\File1.csv
D:\Temp\AllTheFolders\SubFolder2\File2.csv
D:\Temp\AllTheFolders\SubFolder3\File3.csv

I've tried everything I can think of but I can't get it to work....

```
Clear-Host
$DirectoryPath = "D:\Temp\AllTheFolders"
$ServerName    = "MY_SERVER_NAME"
$DatabaseName  = "MY_DATABASE_NAME"
$OutputData    = ""

# Open Connection
$Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerName;Database=$DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0"
$Conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Conn.Open()

# Create the Command object to execute the queries
$Cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$Cmd.Connection = $Conn
$Cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text

# Get Foldernames into Variable for ForEach Loop
$FolderPath = get-childitem  -path "$DirectoryPath\"  | where-object {$_.Psiscontainer -eq "True"} | select-object name

# Loop through folders in Directory
foreach ($DFSfolder in $FolderPath)
{

# For Each Folder obtain objects in a specified directory, recurse then filter for .csv file type, obtain the filename, then group, sort and show the file name and total incidences of it.
$FileInformation = get-childitem -path "$DirectoryPath\$($DFSfolder.name)" -recurse -filter *.csv | select name, LastWriteTime
$FileRowCount = get-childitem -path "$DirectoryPath\$($DFSfolder.name)" -Filter *.csv -Recurse | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line

# Write Data
foreach ($ServerName in $OutputData)
{

# Construct Query
$queryIfDrop = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[OutputTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OutputTable](
    [DirectoryPath] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [SqlExecutionDate] [date] NULL,
    [WMILastWriteTime] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [TodaysFile] [int] NULL,
    [SqlRecordCount] [int] NULL,
    [WMIRecordCount] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END;
"

$queryInsert  = "INSERT INTO dbo.[OutputTable] (DirectoryPath, FileName, WMILastWriteTime, WMIRecordCount) VALUES ('" + "$DirectoryPath\$($DFSfolder.name)" + "', '" + $FileInformation.name + "', '" + $FileInformation.LastWriteTime + "', '" + $FileRowCount.Lines + "');"
$queryDelete  = "DELETE FROM dbo.[OutputTable] WHERE [FileName] = '';"
$queryUpdate1 = "" #"UPDATE dbo.[OutputTable] SET [SqlExecutionDate] = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)) where [SqlExecutionDate] IS NULL;"
$queryUpdate2 = "UPDATE dbo.[OutputTable] SET [TodaysFile] = 1 WHERE [SqlExecutionDate] = substring([WMILastWriteTime],7,4) + '-' + left([WMILastWriteTime],2) + '-' + substring([WMILastWriteTime],4,2);"
$queryUpdate3 = "UPDATE dbo.[OutputTable] SET [TodaysFile] = 0 WHERE [TodaysFile] IS NULL;"

# Construct Complete Sql Server Command
$Cmd.CommandText = $queryIfDrop + " " + $queryInsert + " " + $queryDelete + " " + $queryUpdate1 + " " + $queryUpdate2 + " " + $queryUpdate3

# Execute Command
$Result = $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
}
}

$Conn.Close()
```

Comment: You need to use `Get-Content` to get the paths from the file in place of `Get-ChildItem` which you're using to find the paths from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just get the content of the config file and then you loop through lines:

```
$ServerName    = "MY_SERVER_NAME"
$DatabaseName  = "MY_DATABASE_NAME"


# Open Connection
$Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerName;Database=$DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0"
$Conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Conn.Open()

# Create the Command object to execute the queries
$Cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$Cmd.Connection = $Conn
$Cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text

#Make sure table exists
# Construct Query
$queryIfDrop = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [DirectoryPath] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [SqlExecutionDate] [date] NULL,
    [WMILastWriteTime] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [TodaysFile] [int] NULL,
    [SqlRecordCount] [int] NULL,
    [WMIRecordCount] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END;
"
# Construct Complete Sql Server Command
$Cmd.CommandText = $queryIfDrop;
# Execute Command
$Result = $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

#Now let's iterate over all files and write down updates to SQL

$allfilenames = Get-Content [yourconfigfile]

# Instead of foreach($DFSfolder in $FolderPath)
# Loop through content of the configuration file 
# You will get full path in each iteration
foreach ($filename in $allfilenames) {
    #Then just count the lines   
    $FileRowCount = Get-Content $filename| Measure-Object -Line
    $fileLastWriteTime = (Get-Item -Path $filename).LastWriteTime
    Write-Host "Inserting $filename : $FileRowCount"
    # And write  $filename, $FileRowCount etc to SQL Server
$queryInsert  = "INSERT INTO dbo.[MyTable] (DirectoryPath, FileName, WMILastWriteTime, WMIRecordCount) VALUES ('Directory','$filename', '$fileLastWriteTime', $($FileRowCount.Lines) );"

$Cmd.CommandText = $queryInsert;
# Execute Command
$Result = $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

}

$Conn.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've tried using Get-Content to loop through the file but I just get nothing returned.  I'm unclear as to where to put the syntax and how to completely construct it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? That if you put lines as above in the config file and you do Get-Content myconfigfile you get nothing in return?

Comment: I've basically taken your example and in a separate Powershell UI window and I can get the code to return the list of file names I have written into the .txt file the Powershell loops through.<BR><BR>

I have then tried to apply this logic to the main Powershell script in my original post and I get zero rows returned.  I'm pretty sure I'm not placing your example syntax in the right place and I could also be using/referencing your example code incorrectly.

Comment: This is where I am currently at with the script.  I'm struggling to get the Last Write Time in the code:

Comment: @ChrisKitchen I believe that part of ps1 script is wrong, your foreach ($ServerName in $OutputData) doesn't make sense to me as $OutputData is empty string. I've updated ps1 script above - it will insert new row for each file.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  However, when I execute the code it returns x2 errors...

Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
At line:55 char:1
+ $Result = $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Comment: and this one...

Inserting C:\Temp\SubFolder1\File1.csv : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TextMeasureInfo
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid object name 'dbo.OutputTable'."
At line:53 char:1
+ $Result = $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Comment: @ChrisKitchen, regarding the 2nd problem to - There was "OutputTable" on insert & "MyTable" on create. Fixed that. Can you try now - it will not write the last time but it should create new row for each file

Comment: thank you. The Powershell syntax is now writing to the table. The only problem I now have is how to get the LastWriteTime from the file into the column in the table.

Comment: @ChrisKitchen - updated answer: $fileLastWriteTime = (Get-Item -Path $filename).LastWriteTime & then you just write it into sql

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the script is working exactly how I want it to work :)